# How to change the text cursor (caret) size

Tags: macos

Is there any way to change the size of the blinking text cursor (**not** the mouse cursor)? It is sometimes quite hard to find after switching to another application.

I'm using macOS Sierra, if that's relevant. It's easy to find how to change the mouse cursor size, but I don't see a setting for the text cursor, which is rather tiny. :-(

Comment: The term, btw is `caret` or `I-Beam` - I don't think it's possible - ref https://superuser.com/questions/429464/change-the-width-and-color-of-mac-os-x-text-caret-cursor but I'll just leave this as a comment in case someone manages to find something better.

Answer (score 1):

Your quest on how to change the text cursor is an unusual one outside the norm of utilities offered. 
Therefore an Apple Tech Supporter or Developer  may advise you as to the best avenue. Please go to apple support: https://support.apple.com next click on the white area box: Search Apple Support... a drop down window appears. Select 'Contact Apple Support' now click on 'talk to us' and select the method of contact i.e. personal phone call from Apples Support team or on-line chat.
The Apple Representative will guide you through the process as needed if available.  To the Best of my knowledge, it's best not to guess or take the advise off of the Internet unless trusted. Ask Apple directly sense this is a valid request but not offered in the OS X Sierra utilities.
Authored Statements:  ysureican Fogarty